# How to use a C# serial port in the way it is used in Python

Tags: c#, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to send the bytes (b'\x03\r') to a device on COM5. The result will be the micropython board on the other end crashing. The python code results in the board freezing (As intended). The C# code results in no changes on the device's end, and the serial port not working until it is replugged. How can I get the C# code to do the same thing that the python code does?

This python code works:

```py
import serial # this is installed with 'pip install pyserial'

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM5',
    baudrate=115200,
)
ser.write(b'\x03\r')
```

I tried to make this C# code to do the same thing but it does not work

```cs
using System.IO.Ports;
public static class tester {
    public static void main(/* String[] args */) {
        SerialPort sport = new SerialPort("COM5", 115200); 
        sport.Open();
        sport.Write(new byte[]{0x03, 0xD}, 0, 2);
        sport.Close();
    }
}
```

Thanks for trying to help me :)

Comment: Isn't the data you send `{0x03, 0x0D}` instead of `{0x03, 0x13}`?

Comment: @kunif thanks, I was doing some testing with using 3 and 13 instead of 0x03 and 0x0D

Comment: For example, you can try various things, such as explicitly setting properties such as `Handshake/DtrEnable/RtsEnable`, or waiting until `BytesToWrite` becomes 0 before `Close()`. Or how about checking the difference when sending with other terminal software such as PuTTY?

Comment: You can't ignore the handshake signals in .NET, having them set wrong can make the device decide that it is not connected.  pyserial defaults to HandShake.None, DtrEnable = true and RtsEnable = true.  And best to explicitly specify StopBits = 1, DataBits = 8 and Parity = none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as @kunif and @Hans Passant said was that I needed to set certain parameters as their defaults are not the same on different implementations of serial port libraries. To use a serial device that works fine with the default settings of PySerial use the following code. You will likely have to change the baud rate based on your specific device.

```cs
SerialPort sport = new SerialPort("COM5", 115200);
// I love StackOverflow
sport.Handshake = Handshake.None;
sport.DtrEnable = true;
sport.RtsEnable = true;
sport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
sport.DataBits = 8;
sport.Parity = Parity.None;
sport.Open();
```